# Does this sport's plan provide too much protein?

Tags: nutrition, bodybuilding, protein

I have found a new sport's plan for me and I liked it a lot. I tried two days ago and today this sport's plan without special nutrition, just with my daily meals.

This is the plan: [Kris Gethin's DTP: 4 Weeks to Maximum Muscle](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-dtp-4-weeks-to-maximum-muscle.html)

I am worried about nutrition and its proteins. This nutrition plan provides ~404 grams of protein every day (without supplementation). Is it too much? Because I weight just 63kg, so I need about 158 grams of protein. +- for sports, so about 200 grams.

Comment: How do you even manage to find a nutrition plan in that pile of advertisements (and I use an adblocker)? If you want specific advice you should line out the nutrition provided in the plan, as [the link might rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: And please read the [faq] and [about] pages, as this is not a forum and questions polling for opinions are off topic.

Comment: I edited your question, if you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert them or edit again.

Comment: I haven't watched the video, but can you add some more information? for example was that 404g based on a ratio of your total body weight or a blanket value given for everyone?  With the exception of people with renal (kidney) problems, most people should be able to digest a large amount of protein.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to check your math.  In his [Nutrition section](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-dtp-nutrition.html), he is saying you'll be getting 6 meals per day, with 35 - 45g of protein per meal.  That is 210 - 270 grams per day.

At your weight (139lbs), he is saying to get 2780 calories per day.  His macro ratio gives you 973 protein calories, 1390 carb calories, and 417 fat calories.

Protein contains 4 calories per gram, carbs contain 9 calories per gram, and fat contains 4 calories per gram.  Knowing this, based on your weight, you would be eating 243.25 grams of protein, 154.4 grams of carbs, and 104.25 grams of fat per day.

The key here is the ratios.  If you are eating 2780 calories per day, those calories will have to come from either protein, carbs, or fat.  So even if you decreased the protein, you would need to add carbs or fat to get the calories.  243 grams of protein is probably a bit high for someone your size, but this is also only a 4 week program, so it's fine.